# Getting the warning "Received unknown topic or partition error in ListOffset request for partition hcf.pool.fox-dtemplate-2"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

So I am running a kafka broker and a kafka client and I went and created the following topics on the kafka broker

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --create --topic  hcf.pool.fox-dtemplate-2 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

The topic creation went fine and when I list the topics on kafka, I can see it.

Now when i start my Spring Boot Application which runs the Kafka consumer. I constantly see the message being printed on the console

```
2021-03-29 14:15:19.734  WARN 96875 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=####, groupId=####] Received unknown topic or partition error in ListOffset request for partition hcf.pool.fox-dtemplate-2
```

And this line keeps getting printed on the console multiple times every 200 ms.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Kafka docker image - confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1

Also, how can I check the Kafka consumer version?

Comment: Are you using the correct bootstrap-server in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the topic via Kafka instead of ZK

```
$ kafka-topics 
Create, delete, describe, or change a topic.
Option                                   Description                            
------                                   -----------                            
...
--bootstrap-server <String: server to    REQUIRED: The Kafka server to connect  
  connect to>                              to. In case of providing this, a     
                                           direct Zookeeper connection won't be 
                                           required.                            
...
--zookeeper <String: hosts>              DEPRECATED, The connection string for  
                                           the zookeeper connection in the form 
                                           host:port. Multiple hosts can be     
                                           given to allow fail-over.
```

Comment: So what should I put for the argument --bootstrap-server ?

Comment: Whatever you have in you spring bootstrap servers.

Comment: Or you can let spring create it by adding a NewTopic @Bean. See the spring-kafka reference manual Configuring Topics.

Comment: I tried doing this as well,


`@Bean
    public NewTopic templateEventTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name(KafkaConfigUtil.templateTopicName)
                .partitions(numPartition)
                .replicas(numReplicas)
                .build();
    }'

It still does not work, I tried providing --bootstrap-server  as well, same issue!

Comment: And. If it is not working, edit the question to show your code and configuration.

Comment: Kafka instead of ZK shouldn't matter. I second using NewTopic bean, though